# Multiplication of Eigen vectors with matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have vectors $c_k$ $(N \times 1)$, $k=1,\ldots$,K and a symmetric matrix $L (K \times N)$. I wish to maximize the following:

$\max_{(c_k)} \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_k^T L c_k$

Is it true to claim that the solution $c_k$ are the eigen vectors of $L$?

Thanks you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is there any condition on $||c_k||$? Otherwise the sum can get arbitrarily big

Comment: $L$ is $N \times N$.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ill-formed because

- the maximum is unbounded, and
- if we constrain the vectors to be unit, in general there will be a unique $c$ that maximizes $c^TLc$, so that the solution will be $c_k=c$ for all $k$.

Also note that if the Eigenvalues are all negative, the maximum is achieved by the vector $0$.